# jquery create advanced search(text, menu, slider) web database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, menu

I Want to create a search page in my app using jquery and html. My database is in chrome web database. Now it just has an interface framework. I have seen some tutorials but none of them mentions the menu or slider. I don't know how to get value from them. And I did try to get the `depMenu` value using `var depMenu = $("#depMenu option:selected").val();`, but it seems like just get the first value, so I think it may need refresh at first. But these two `//depMenu[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    //depMenu.selectmenu("refresh");`can't work at all.

I'm very hurried to work it out, any help  thanks in advanced!!

Here is html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="ASearch" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Search
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="search">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <input name="" id="TextSearch" placeholder="enter your search term here" value="" type="search" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="depMenu">
                    Department:
                </label>

                <select id="depMenu" name="" data-theme="b">
                    <option value="View all">
                        All department
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Ladies
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Men
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Kids
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="actMenu">
                <label for="actMenu">
                    Activities:
                </label>
                <select id="actMenu" name="" data-theme="b">
                    <option value="option1">
                        All activites
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Camping
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Walking
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Skiing
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Climbing
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Travel
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Cycling
                    </option>
                    <option value="value">
                        Fishing
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="slider">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <label for="slider">
                        Price
                    </label>
                    <input id="slider" type="range" name="slider" value="50" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="d" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <input id="ClearButton" type="submit" data-theme="c" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" value="Clear" />
            <input id="SubButton" type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div><!--/page-->
```

Here is the database:

```
    function createDatabaseAndPopulateRecords() {
    //set-up datavase name , version, displayname,max size
    db = openDatabase('outdoorsshop', '1.0', 'beactiveshop', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

    db.transaction(function (txs) {
        txs.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shops (id unique, name TEXT, price TEXT, department INTEGER, activities INTEGER,\
             large INTEGER, descr TEXT, img TEXT)');
        txs.executeSql('DELETE FROM shops');
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['1', 'Mens Workout clothes ', '£38', '2', '0', 'brand: Lefan / Lu Iraq Sanskrit color-coded: black Item: 21 817 sportswear size (non-mandatory): M L XL', 'image/cmen2.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['2', 'Road Iraqi Sanskrit  ', '£64', '2', '0', 'Fitness apparel leader brand Aerobics clothing, mens movement suite', 'image/cmen1.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['3', 'Autumn ladies lipstick', '£95', '1', '0', 'the same paragraph of shinee key fx Amber Autumn ladies lipstick baseball uniform sweater coat couple shirt', 'image/cladies1.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['4', 'Female genuine badminton clothing ', '£125', '1', '0', 'Mr Adams parked the spring new female genuine badminton clothing fitness sportswear ', 'image/cladies2.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['5', 'Bodysuit', '£87', '3', '0', 'Short-sleeved bodysuit in soft jersey with a print on the front and press-studs on one shoulder and at the crotch. 95% cotton, 5% ', 'image/ckids1.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['6', 'Leisure hammock ', '£121', '0', '1', 'Tmall season only swim the authentic outdoor and indoor leisure hammock widening canvas thick double hammock', 'image/camp1.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['7', 'Single hammock ', '£88', '0', '1', ' Really useful funky looking small daypack. Its very light weight and snug comfy fit round the body makes it one of our most popular packs for everyday use.', 'image/camp2.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['8', 'CNHIMALAYA', '£199', '0', '2', 'Luxury Design Three Room Leisure 5-6 Person Family Camping Tent', 'image/tent1.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['9', 'Large Camping Tents For Sale ', '£18.5', '0', '2', 'Product Name: Antelope Super Large Rain-Proof Camping Tent Brand: Antelope SKU: cp0076 Weight: 9kg', 'image/tent2.jpg']);
        txs.executeSql('INSERT INTO shops (id, name, price, department, activities, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', ['10', 'Fiberglass transparent fishing rod ', '£18.5', '0', '2', 'Fishing rod pole in hand, sea fishing rod, hand sea dual-purpose rod three. Sea fishing rod length is about 1.6 meters - 2.4 meters, have longer.', 'image/fishing1.jpg']);
    });
}
```

Here is jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // getting the value that user typed
    var searchString = $("#TextSearch").val();

    // forming the queryString
    var data = 'search=' + searchString;

    var depMenu = $("#depMenu option:selected").val();
    //depMenu[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    //depMenu.selectmenu("refresh");



    $("#SubButton").on("click", function (e) {
        var asearchString = $(this).val();

        alert($("#TextSearch").data());
        alert(depMenu);
        //var v = search.val().toLowerCase();
        if (depMenu == "view all") {
            db.transaction(function (txsLadies) {
                txsLadies.executeSql('SELECT * FROM shops WHERE shops.department=1', [], function (txs, ladies_results) {
                    var len1 = ladies_results.rows.length, i;
                    $("#SearchResultList").empty();
                    alert('Failed because');
                    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++) {  //for each record in the resultse
                        var LadiesRecord = ladies_results.rows.item(i);  //get the current record from the database recordse
                        //.append funciton to add records
                        $('#SearchResultList').append("<div style=\"border-bottom:1px solid black;padding:10px;margin:10px;\">" +
                        LadiesRecord.name + "(" + LadiesRecord.price + ") Rating: " + LadiesRecord.img + "</div>");

                    }
                    $("#SearchResultList").hide();
                });
            });
        } else {
            return false;
            alert('Failed because');
        }

    });
});

 $('#ClearButton').live('click', function () {

        var myselect = $("#depMenu");
        myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        myselect.selectmenu("refresh");

    });

});
```